# What does exports.run = async (client, message, args) => do Discord.js

Tags: async.js

in a previous question I got a very good answer but i don't understand what this means KEEP IN MIND THIS IS DISCORD.JS

`exports.run = async (client, message, args) =>`

the whole code is

```
const roles = {
  ':harrison:': '794924635778973716',
  ':banana': '794924670955814943',
}

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  await message.delete()

  // because RoleManager.fetch is async
  const rolesArray = await Promise.all(Object.entries(roles)
    .map(async ([emoji, id]) => `${emoji} ${(await message.guild.roles.fetch(id)).toString()}`)
  )
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Roles')
    .setDescription(`
      Tip: *Double React to remove a role*

      ${rolesArray.join('\n')}
    `)
    .setColor(colors.purple)
    .setFooter('Wilderbot')

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
    const emojis = Object.keys(roles)
    for (const emoji of emojis) await msg.react(emoji)

    // only collect reactions that are the role emojis
    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(({emoji}) => emojis.includes(emoji.name))

    collector.on('collect', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(member => {
        member.roles.add(roles[emoji.name])
      })
    })

    collector.on('remove', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(member => {
        member.roles.remove(roles[emoji.name])
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: So you have some (more or less random) code snippet (supposedly taken from some library). How do you expect anybody except the original author to know what this code does, when there is no context at all?

Comment: oops sorry it's a discord.js thing i just forgot to put it in the title

Answer (score 0):

This looks like code for a relaction role command. "exports.run = async (client, message, args) =>" is used in conjunction to a command handler. the "async" part is telling javascript that this is an asyncronous function, therefore allowing the use of "await" and ".then".